# SSRS Prefilter PArameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am working on the report in SSRS and I would like to select default values from the parameter section.... I have something like this:

[image]

As you can see all the values are selected.... but I would like to have something prefiltered like this:

[image]

Keep all the values but only show the most important for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Report Parameter properties - >

Under General - > Set  Data type  & check  option - Allow multiple values and Parameter visibility to visible ,

Under Available values either specify values / Get values from a query  ,

Under Default values - > specify values - > Add - > mention the value

( Note : Make sure default value you are specifying should be one among the multiple values of the parameter dataset , only then default value that is one among the multiple valued paramter will be checked by default when you preview the report